# Why am I unable to link my Stack Overflow Careers profile to SO profile?

Tags: support, profile-page

In my profile, even after I click `Discover Stack Overflow Careers`, I still see the following message, instead of link to my SO Career page.

> No Careers profile for this account; click the link to find out more!

Comment: Same problem here. Clicking on "Discover..." goes to my Careers profile but no link to Careers in my SO profile.

Comment: There's a solution: see my answer below.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Solution**

Toggle the Careers account privacy settings to private then back to public.

[Source: *'New profile pages are out - bugs and feedback master list'*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253471/148742)

Comment: Where is that link I don't see it

Comment: @GabrielRodriguez do you mean the link to your StackOverflow Careers profile on your StackOverflow profile? Have you got already a Careers account?

Comment: Yes, im there I just  don't see how to toggle the privacy

Comment: ok, I found it put it says: Your profile is currently private and the `make my profile public` button is disabled..why?

Comment: ok ok ok found it, I was missing my username custom url field

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302477/unable-to-link-personal-careers-page-to-stack-overflow-profile