# Stack Careers: Profile Found, but Hidden: is this a bug or am I failing to understand what it is trying to tell me?

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page

I definitely have a SC account: https://careers.stackoverflow.com/lordmatt however when I edited my profile the box for said link says that I did not have one yet and it will show up when I do.

So I googled it. After reading a few other questions and answers I clicked on "Discover Stack Overflow Careers" which takes me to my SC profile. I set my profile to private and back to public which got me to

```
"Profile [is] Found, but Hidden"
```

Naturally I ticked the show profile box and saved. The message is the same so now I am wondering if it is hidden but shown (which would equate to not hidden IMHO). Is there a layer of meaning in this rather cryptic UI message that I am missing or is this simply a case of something that is still waiting for improvements?

(Given that this has left me scratching my head can I tentatively suggest that this message might be a candidate for further consideration?)

Answer (score 6):

## Short Answer

We need to save, wait, and then refresh.

As Matthew correctly mentioned in his comment, there is a delay, after which hitting refresh shows the new message that it is shared.

## To show my existing, public profile took these steps.

1. Go to my StackOverflow profile editing page.
2. It currently says:

> No Careers profile for this account ([This is the first bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290488/why-am-i-unable-to-link-my-stackoverflow-career-profile-to-so-profile) - I already have one.)

3. So, go to my existing, public, careers profile page.
4. Toggle from public, back to private, and back to public again.
5. Return to my Stack Overflow profile page.
6. Refresh.
7. It now says:

> Profile found, but Hidden (This is the second bug - it's already public.)

[image: Profile found, but Hidden]

8. So, save my StackOverflow profile page.
9. Refresh.
10. It now says:

> Profile Linked.

[image: Profile Linked]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your Careers profile was found, but is currently hidden on your Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange profile page - that is, you are not sharing it.

Comment: I have ticked the box to share it. Is there an option somewhere that I am being too dumb to spot?

Comment: Did you save the edit form (button at the bottom of the page)?

Comment: I did indeed save. I mentioned saving specifically in my question because it occurred to me that this might be an easily missed step. (That was why I used the bug tag).

Comment: I can see a link to your careers page on your profile. And the message has changed on your profile edit page.

Comment: It appears that there is a delay after which hitting refresh shows the new message that it is shared. I say this as now the expected message is shown.

Comment: Pay attention to that last part: "that is, you are not sharing it."